# Strong primes in cryptography, their relation to complexity theory and security

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, cryptography

According to the lecture slide by Shafi Goldwasser a prime is a strong prime if:

$$p = 2q + 1$$ for some prime q.

For me it, seems a bit arbitrary that is the definition of a strong prime in cryptography. Is there a computational complexity reason of why this is the definition of a strong prime in cryptography? What are the advantages of this type of prime over other different types of prime numbers? Does anyone has a intuition or a rigorous mathematical argument to defend why this is a good definition of a "hard prime" in the context of cryptography? In terms of security, how is this a good definition? I am not even sure what the word "hard" is adding to the definition.

I guess I am trying to look for a more theoretical argument to support whatever this definition is trying to achieve. Arguments on the lines on "it does well in practice" will not suffice to answer my question. I am looking for a more mathematical reason/intuition for why this is a good definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the only definition of "strong prime", according to Wikipedia.
Anyway, the motivation seems to be that  [Pollard's p-1 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_-_1_algorithm) can find a 
number's prime factors $p$ such that $p-1$ has only small prime factors.
If $p-1 = 2q$ where $q$ is prime, this won't happen.

Comment: [Pohlig-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) discrete logarithm algorithm is another example of an cryptanalytic attack which can be prevented by making sure $p-1$ has a large prime factor.